# Organic Chemistry - Reduction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, organic-reduction

Can anybody help me with the product? Seems like Birch reduction, but Birch reduction is used for conjugated systems and alkynes.

[image]

Comment: Looks like isomerising the tri-substituted double bond

Comment: Can't find any such reaction in Reaxys...

Comment: Stupid question: Is the top of that structure cut-off to obscure a oxygen in the form of a carbonyl?

Comment: There exists a similar rxn Bouveault–Blanc reduction used for reduction of esters to primary alcohols and this reagent can reduce $\alpha,\beta-$unsaturated ketones

Comment: @Zhe it is not a carbonyl... I found the question as it.